# Vertically Align Stacked Content

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I have a div that acts as a tooltip-like popup when the mouse hovers over a link. It conceptually has 5 rows: A line of text, a button, a divider, a line of text, a button.

```
 ----------------
|   Click here:  |
|    [Button1]   |
|   ----------   |
| Or Click Here: |
|    [Button2]   |
 -------  -------
        \/
```

Each row is currently a div with an image background for its content and it's all working fine. But now we have a need to display combinations of the top and bottom button conditionally. How can I keep the visible elements vertically centered in the popup div as "rows" are shown or hidden? The popup div needs to have a minimum of 20px padding at the top.

```
 ----------------  ----------------
|                ||                |
| Or Click Here: ||   Click here:  |
|    [Button2]   ||    [Button1]   |
|                ||                |
|                ||                |
 -------  -------  -------  -------
        \/                \/
```

I've read this: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/centervertically.html but I'm not sure how to apply it with multiple stacked contents.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you need....are you saying you want the popups to be like the first example you show, except with one of the buttons hidden? Or do you need to popups to just have one button and be vertically centered?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, so it can look like the first one, or I might hide one of the buttons, its associated text, and the divider line. At that point I want it to automatically adjust to vertically center the remaining visible content (what I was trying to show in the second two examples).

Comment: I think I've been working in WPF for so long I forgot DHTML is one big hack (for the things we use it for now days at least). After remembering I decided why not hack some more. I first attempted to use javascript to intelligently recalculate the top margin to center the content for me. Because of IE's disregard for standards, that got too messy. So I ended up using javascript to swap out css classes on the divs in order to adjust top & bottom margins and make it look centered instead. I'd still be interested in hearing a good way to implement it automatically though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm already using javascript to show or hide the elements, I decided to use it to set the alignment as well. I first attempted to use javascript to intelligently recalculate the top margin to center the content for me. Because of IE's disregard for standards, that got too messy. So I ended up using javascript to swap out css classes on the divs in order to adjust top & bottom margins and make it look centered instead. The divs are already stacking so if I remove the top div, the remaining ones shift up. So the class I swap in just adds the appropriate top margin to shift the top div down to the center.

Answer (score 0):

try this style for the container div:

```
<div style='display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle'></div>
```

Comment: That has no effect (in FireFox, at least). Thanks though.